# htaccess RewriteRule throwing 404

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, netsuite

I am trying to get a wordpress site to Rewrite to a NetSuite page, keeping the Wordpress URL but taking the user to the NetSuite page.

For examle
User types in http://sighfye.com/my/111/2222 and they go to

https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=X&compid=XXXXXXX&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=1116&ref=2222

In there url they will still see http://sighfye.com/my/111/2222

And the parameters 111 and 2222 are fed into the netsuite url.

This is my htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?(\w+)?/?$ 
"https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=X&compid=XXXXXXX&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=$1&ref=$2&api=$3" [P]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Whenever I test this and go to http://sighfye.com/my/111/2222 I get a 404 error.

Note: These give urls are for example only and this the real urls.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://sighfye.com/my/111/2222 https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=X&compid=XXXXXXX&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=1116&ref=2222 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Priyanka. Unfortunately it does not seem to work. From what I am reading it's not possible to redirect while keeping the typed URL :(